# Does Golang do any conversion when casting a byte slice to a string?

Tags: string, casting, go, byte, slice

Does Golang do any conversion or somehow try to interpret the bytes when casting a byte slice to a string? I've just tried with a byte slice containing a null byte and it looks like it still keep the string as it is.

```
var test []byte
test = append(test, 'a')
test = append(test, 'b')
test = append(test, 0)
test = append(test, 'd')
fmt.Println(test[2] == 0) // OK
```

But how about strings with invalid unicode points or UTF-8 encoding. Could the casting fail or the data be corrupted?

Comment: As the answerers said, Go does not convert anything. ([Rob Pike explaining Go strings](http://blog.golang.org/strings) may or may not illuminate this question for you, but reading it can only be a good thing.) `string`<=>`[]byte` conversions _do_ copy the raw bytes, though, because `string`s are immutable and `[]byte`s are not. So taking out unneeded conversions could reduce garbage, for example.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [String types](http://golang.org/ref/spec#String_types)
>
> A string type represents the set of string values. A string value is a
>   (possibly empty) sequence of bytes.
>
> [Conversions](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions)
>
> Conversions to and from a string type
>
> Converting a slice of bytes to a string type yields a string whose
>   successive bytes are the elements of the slice.
>
> ```
> string([]byte{'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', '\xc3', '\xb8'})   // "hellø"
> string([]byte{})                                     // ""
> string([]byte(nil))                                  // ""
>
> type MyBytes []byte
> string(MyBytes{'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', '\xc3', '\xb8'})  // "hellø"
> ```
>
> Converting a value of a string type to a slice of bytes type yields a
>   slice whose successive elements are the bytes of the string.
>
> ```
> []byte("hellø")   // []byte{'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', '\xc3', '\xb8'}
> []byte("")        // []byte{}
>
> MyBytes("hellø")  // []byte{'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', '\xc3', '\xb8'}
> ```

A string value is a (possibly empty) sequence of bytes. A string value may or may not represent Unicode characters encoded in UTF-8. There is no interpretation of the bytes during the conversion from `byte` slice to `string` nor from `string` to `byte` slice. Therefore, the bytes will not be changed and the conversions will not fail.

Answer (score 5):

No, the casting can't fail. Here's an example showing this (run in the Go Playground):

```
b := []byte{0x80}
s := string(b)
fmt.Println(s)
fmt.Println([]byte(s))
for _, c := range s {
    fmt.Println(c)
}
```

This prints:

```
�
[128]
65533
```

Note that ranging over invalid UTF-8 is well defined according to the [Go spec](http://golang.org/ref/spec):

> For a string value, the "range" clause iterates over the Unicode code
>   points in the string starting at byte index 0. On successive
>   iterations, the index value will be the index of the first byte of
>   successive UTF-8-encoded code points in the string, and the second
>   value, of type rune, will be the value of the corresponding code
>   point. If the iteration encounters an invalid UTF-8 sequence, the
>   second value will be 0xFFFD, the Unicode replacement character, and
>   the next iteration will advance a single byte in the string.